# How to run Node on one URL, on GoDaddy (shared hosting), along with Apache

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

I installed Node on my GoDaddy's Linux shared hosting plan via SSH. Running Node on a specific port number isn't a problem.

(I'm not at all clear about this ecosystem, which is why my question might sound stupid)

The primary (WordPress) website runs on Apache and I cannot disturb that permanently (that is, I cannot stop that website from running and enable Node on all ports)

Is there any way to run Node on one specific URL of the website, instead of a port number?

I read a few answers and a few articles and tried to modify the .htaccess file and enable reverse proxy, but I can't get it to work especially since I'm not even sure about how it works.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy no. Like I said, I could get it to work on one port number, not a URL. This is completely unrelated, but if you're using a JS framework on the frontend, you can use proxies to interact with the server on that specific port.